# How to rebind global declare list in App.xaml.cs in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, list, global

i have list of custom class declare globally in App.xaml.cs and binding on first button click , in this way its working fine , but on second button click i want to clear list items and rebind new items, but its showing previous bind elements ,

i tried to clear first before binding but it shows nothing(i think its initialize only once for an application)

DeptWiseidAndName this list is declared public in App.xaml.cs

List EditList = new List();

```
        EditList = App_Object.DeptWiseidAndName;
        App_Object.DeptWiseidAndName.Clear();
```

plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an ObservableCollection instead of List. ObservableCollection alerts changes to its contents to object which bind to it.